# Stacked full-page divs

Tags: html, css

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JzbDj/

I'm trying to get each of my divs to fill the viewport without specifying a size in pixels. How can I do this? Currently, the divs are only as large as the text in the h1 and p elements inside of them. I tried setting the height to 100%, and doing the same for the html and body elements ...

```
<title>mountains</title>
<body>
    <div id="denali" class="fullPageDiv">
        <h1>denali</h1>
        <p>Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mountlogan" class="fullPageDiv">
        <h1>mount logan</h1>
        <p>Mount Logan is the second tallest peak in North America.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    font: 18px/30px Sans-serif; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height:1000px;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.fullPageDiv {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#denali {
    background-color: red;
}

#mountlogan {
    background-color: green;
}

#citl {
background-color: yellow;
}

#mountsaintelias {
    background-color: blue;
}



#popo {
background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: just another demo http://demo.venomvendor.com/pure-css-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

instead of `min-height`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JzbDj/2/)**

Comment: Awesome, that's what I'm looking for! I swear I tried that ... there must have been some other css that was breaking it. Unless combining "html, body" into one selector somehow makes a difference ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Javascript if I understood your question correctly,
Include jQuery & this code:

```
////Checks the viewport height and sets element's height accordingly.
$(".fullPageDiv").css({height:$(window).height()});                        

////If viewport ever re-sized or device (tablet for example) switched from portrait to landscape or vice versa.
                                      $(window).resize(function(){
 $(".fullPageDiv").css({height:$(window).height()});
});
```

**Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JzbDj/3/)**

Comment: Thanks Sony, that's great. I'll use the jQuery if the simpler answer becomes inadequate...